# Error with 'invalid subscript type 'list'?

Tags: r, class

I'm using the lcmm package in R to model longitudinal data, but I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to use the postprob function to get the posterior probabilities of the latent classes, and then use these to assign each observation to a class. However, when I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
Error in groups$class[sapply(data$id, function(x) which(groups$id == x))] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
data( bmi_long, package = "LCTMtools" )
data <- data.frame(bmi_long)

data$id <- as.numeric(data$id)
data$x <-data$age
data$y<-as.numeric(data$bmi)
data <-subset(data, select=c("id", "x", "y"))

m1 <- lcmm(fixed=y ~ x, subject = 'id', data = data)
summary(m1)
postprob(m1)
data$id <- as.numeric(data$id)
groups <- as.data.frame(m1$pprob[,1:2])
data$groups <- factor(groups$class[sapply(data$id, function(x) which(groups$id==x))])
```

Comment: Try this: Use `unlist` before `sapply` like `data$groups <- factor(groups$class[unlist(sapply(data$id, function(x) which(groups$id==x)))])`

Comment: thank you. 

I also get this error, if you by chance have any immediate suggestions, I would be very appreciative! 
 - 
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, groups, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 39964 rows, data has 40000